# Paging setting is not remembered on custom search tab

Tags: bug, new-nav, pagination

There are 3 options for page sizes, 15, 30, and 50.

I always select 50. However, on the new setup, *the custom tabs do not remember the page size* and I find myself having to constantly correct the issue.

Steps to reproduce this issue:

1. Have a custom tab.
2. Click on the custom tab to get the question results.
3. Select 50 as the page size.
4. Click on any question in the result set.
5. Once at the question, click on the main "Questions" link.
6. Click on the custom tab.
7. Note that the page size is back to 15.

Comment: This has been driving me bananas for weeks.  I'm working on cleaning up "older" unanswered (and poorly-answered) questions, and each time I look at one, I have to start my search again.  Yes, I could open the question in a new tab, but I already have far, far too many browser tabs open.

Comment: Yeah, it bothers me almost every day too! :(