# Questions-per-page choice (pagination page size) is forgotten

Tags: bug, questions, new-nav, pagination

At the bottom of the questions page there is a control for how many questions to show per page:

[image]

I've noticed lately on Stack Overflow* that my preferred setting for that (30) is getting lost when I go away for some time and then come back. It gets remembered for a short time, but not if I'm away for a while (hour or so). I guess it's remembered in some kind of session-specific storage.

Could it be remembered in a more durable way, please?

Note: I'm participating in [testing the new navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814), if that's relevant.

Shadow Wizard found [this question about it not working on custom tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272043/paging-setting-is-not-remembered-on-custom-search-tab); I'm not on a custom tab (I'm on `*Newest`), but it's probably the same root cause.

*(* Haven't noticed either way on other sites, don't participate in them enough.)*

Comment: Marking as bug,  since the intended behavior is for the system to remember your last choice. Not doing so means something broke.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Ah, thanks. Wasn't sure it was the intended behavior.

Comment: Yeah, it remembers the last choice for me for years, never had any trouble with that. (And I opted out the new nav long ago, so good chance it's indeed something with the new nav.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Excellent, that helps us narrow it down to the new-nav -- added the tag. It remembered my setting for years too.

Comment: Do you happen to be in the "custom"  tab? If so, it's a dupe of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272043/paging-setting-is-not-remembered-on-custom-search-tab). (If not, it's related but no dupe)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, but it's probably the same root cause. I added a link to that in the question.